# Do thermal printers have a standard paper size?

Tags: printing, printer, paper

Do thermal printers have a standard paper size like for example A4 papers? I know each thermal printer differs but [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-ZJ-5890K-Mini-58mm-Low-Noise-POS-Receipt-Thermal-Printer-with-USB-Port-EU-PLUG/32642621640.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10068_10344_10345_10342_10343_10340_10341_10540_10307_10303_10060_10302_10155_10154_10056_10055_10539_10054_10538_10537_10059_10536_10534_10533_100031_10099_10103_10102_5590020_10052_5640020_10053_10107_10050_10142_10051_10084_10083_5370020_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10179_10312_10313_10314_10078_10079_10073,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=b688bc3c-85f9-446a-8417-9d3190fc1506&algo_expid=977b8cb4-947a-4f80-982f-2da30597b02d-0&algo_pvid=977b8cb4-947a-4f80-982f-2da30597b02d), for example uses a 57mm max paper size.

Comment: To my knowledge, thermal printers do not have a standard paper size. They have paper standards, but that's different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No.

Thermal printers do not conform to any particular standard when it comes to the media they support. In fact, thermal printers are often designed for a specific range of paper sizes based on the task they're designed for.

For example, a handheld label maker may only accept thermal tape that is 1/2" wide. Conversely, an industrial thermal printer may accept not only a wide variety of paper sizes, but may even accept different types of printing stock, vinyl being one common option.

Answer (score 0):

There are many thermal printers that conform to the A4 paper size. They work with both rolled A4 width and rolled A4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).